# continuity of $L^p$ norms with respect to $p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, normed-spaces

Let $0<p_0<p<p<p_1\leq \infty$. Then I have proved $L^{p_0}(\mu)\cap L^{p_1}(\mu)\subseteq L^{p}(\mu)$. In particular, when $p_0=1$, $p_1=\infty$, I have proved further $||f||_\infty=lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_p$ for any $f\in L^{1}(\mu)\cap L^{\infty}(\mu)$. Does this equality hold for all $p_0,p_1$? How to prove? Does the following map continuous?
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Phi: L^{p_0}(\mu)\cap L^{p_1}(\mu)\times [p_0,p_1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\\
(f,p)\longmapsto ||f||_p 
\end{eqnarray*}
? I have no way to get any solutions. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is continuous.

1. As a function of $p$ (for a fixed $f$) it is continuous by the Dominated convergence theorem. For all $p\in [p_0,p_1]$ we have $|f|^p\le  |f|^{p_0}+|f|^{p_1}$ pointwise. Therefore, as $p\to a\in [p_0,p_1]$, the pointwise convergence $|f|^p\to |f|^a$ implies the convergence of integrals.
2. As a function of $f$ (for a fixed $p$), the $L^p$ norm is a Lipschitz function of $f$ with respect to the distance induced by this norm. This is just a restatement of the triangle inequality. Consequently, the $L^p$ norm is a Lipschitz function on $L^{p_0}\cap L^{p_1}$ equipped with the   norm $\|\cdot\|_{p_0}+\|\cdot\|_{p_1}$.
3. As a function of both: if a function defined on a product of metric spaces  is continuous in one variable and Lipschitz in the other, then it is jointly continuous. (Exercise).