# Lower Semicontinuity of $L^p$ norms with varying exponents

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, calculus-of-variations, weak-convergence, semicontinuous-functions

In a previous post (see [continuity of $L^p$ norms with respect to $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581834/continuity-of-lp-norms-with-respect-to-p)) it is shown that in a measure space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$, if $1\leq p_0\leq p\leq p_1\leq+\infty$,  then the function $\Phi\colon L^{p_0}(\Omega)\cap L^{p_1}(\Omega)\times [p_0,p_1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as

$$ (f,p)\mapsto \|f\|_{p}, $$

where $\|f\|_p$ denotes the norm of $f$ in $L^p(\Omega)$, is continuous with the respect to the metric $d((f_1,q_1),(f_2,q_2)):=\|f_1-f_2\|_{p_0}+\|f_1-f_2\|_{p_1}+|q_1-q_2|$
on the product space $L^{p_0}(\Omega)\cap L^{p_1}(\Omega)\times [p_0,p_1]$.

Is it true that it is sequentially weakly lower semicontinuous as well, i.e., is it true that if $ f_j\rightharpoonup f$ weakly in $L^{q}(\Omega)$ for any $q\in[p_0,p_1]$ and $p_j\rightarrow p$ then

$$\|f\|_{p}\leq \liminf_{j\to\infty} \|f_j\|_{p_j}?$$

It would be enough to prove that the function defined above is convex, but I did not manage doing so. I also tried using Mazur's Lemma to exploit the convexity of the function in the first variable and the fact that it is continuous with respect to the strong convergence in $L^{p_0}(\Omega)\cap L^{p_1}(\Omega)\times [p_0,p_1]$, but it did not help much.

I am not able to produce simple counterexamples with periodic functions either (nor more complex), so I am tempted to say that it is true. Do you have any references, hints or an actual proof (or counterexample) for this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to positively answer to the question in the case where $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite (which was the case I was truly interested in).

Consider $1\leq p_0<p_1\leq\infty$ and assume first that $\mu(\Omega)=1$, where $\mu$ and $\Omega$ are the (non-negative) reference measure and the reference set, respectively. Suppose that $u_j\rightharpoonup u$ weakly in $L^{p_1}(\Omega)$ and $p_j\to p$. Note that, since $\mu(\Omega)<+\infty$, this implies that $u_j\rightharpoonup u$ weakly in $L^{q}(\Omega)$ for any $q\in[p_0,p_1]$.

If $p_j \searrow p$, then by Holder's inequality and the usual lower semicontinuity at fixed exponent we have

$$\liminf_j \|u_j\|_{p_{j}} \geq \liminf_j \|u_j\|_{p} \geq \|u\|_p.$$

If $p_{j}\nearrow p$, upon passing to a proper subsequence (not relabelled), we may assume that

$$\exists\, L:= \lim_j \|u_j\|_{p_{j}} = \liminf_j \|u_j\|_{p_j}  <\infty.$$

By Mazur's lemma, for every $j\in\mathbb{N}$ we find natural numbers $C(j)$ and non negative terms $c_{j,n}$ with naturals $n\in\{j,...,C(j)\}$ such that

$$\sum^{C(j)}_{n={j}}c_{j,n}=1$$

and the functions

$$v_j:=\sum^{C(j)}_{n={j}} c_{j,n} u_{n}, \quad j\in\mathbb{N}$$
strongly converge to $u$ in in $L^q(\Omega)$ for every $q\in[p_0,p_1]$.

Fix $\eta>0$, by the triangular inequality and Holder's inequality we have
\begin{eqnarray*}  \nonumber
\|v_j\|_{p_{j}} \leq && \sum^{C(j)}_{n={j}}c_{j,n} \|u_{n}\|_{p_{j}} \\ \nonumber
\leq && \sum^{C(j)}_{n={j}}c_{j,n} \|u_{n}\|_{p_{n}} \\ \nonumber
\leq && L+\eta
\end{eqnarray*}
for every $j$ eventually large. Passing to the limit in $j$, we get
\begin{equation*} L+\eta \geq  \lim_j \|v_j\|_{p_{j}}\\
= \|u\|_{p},
\end{equation*}
where the last equality follows by the strong convergence (the answer in the question posted above). We conclude by the arbitrariness of $\eta$.

If $1\neq\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, we repeat the above argument changing the reference measure into $\mu':=\mu/\mu(\Omega)$ and the claim follows.

If $\mu(\Omega)=\infty$, assume that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, so that there exists a countable family of measurable sets $\{B_R, R\in \mathbb{N}\}$ such that $\mu(B_R)<\infty$ for every $R$ and $\chi_{B_R} \nearrow 1$ pointwise $\mu-$a.e. in $\Omega$; then define the finite measures $\mu_R$ as the restriction of $\mu$ to $B_R$ and apply the above result to get

$$\liminf_j \|u_j\|_{L^{p_{j}}_{\mu}} \geq \liminf_j \|u_j\|_{L^{p_{j}}_{\mu_R}}  \geq \|u\|_{L^p_{\mu_R}}.
$$
Finally take the supremum among $R\in\mathbb{N}$ to conclude.